# How to deal with a multi-row around a page break OR avoid it by "detecting" the page break and auto-magically breaking before?

Tags: tabularray

Please consider the following MWE and ignore the `minipage` altogether (its only purpose is to use up vertical space to push down the top of the `longtblr` for demonstration):

```latex
% !TeX encoding = UTF-8
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass[paper=a4]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\SetTblrInner[tblr,longtblr]{
    colspec = {|X[1,m]X[1,m]|},
    hlines,
    vlines,
}

\begin{document}
    \centering
    \begin{minipage}[c][16cm][c]{\linewidth}
    \centering
    minipage to take up plenty of vertical space

    (this is meant to push the longtblr way down on the A4 page)
    \end{minipage}

    \begin{longtblr}{cc} % using this to "break" at page breaks
        Table & header \\
        table & content \\
        table & content \\
        table & content \\
        \SetCell[r=2]{m} multi
         & row \\
         & row \#2 \\
        table & content \\
        table & content \\
        table & content \\
        table & content \\
    \end{longtblr}
\end{document}
```

The issue I am trying to address happens just before the page break, which -- if this example is deterministic enough -- will happen to be just where I start the multi-row with `\SetCell[r=2]{m}`.

The question is solely about the `longtblr` in the document. A screenshot demonstrates the problem (the marked spot):

[image: multi-row formatting messed up around page break]

Obviously at a page break I would expect the `longtblr` to exhibit one of three behaviors:

1. fall back from multi-row and use normal rows
2. simply fix the vertical alignment, but keep with the multi-row behavior otherwise
3. somehow detect the page break condition (obviously `longtblr` has something in place already) and doing the page break earlier or later ("stretching" the vertical space

There are probably other behaviors that could yield decent results, but these were the ones I could come up with.

### Question

How can I achieve a decent result **without** having to **manually** intervene by -- say -- counting "real" rows and then inserting a *manual* page break?

**NB:** I am aware that forcing or suppressing a page break can also have undesired effects on the layout. Adding *manual* `\pagebreak` right before the `\SetCell` achieves (3), but isn't an automated solution. Similarly I could make *just* that instance of `\SetCell` use a different vertical alignment, let it page-break as before, but thereby achieving (2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to terminated all rows except last spanned by multirow cell by `\\*`:

```
% !TeX encoding = UTF-8
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass[paper=a4]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\SetTblrInner[tblr,longtblr]{
    colspec = {|X[1,m]X[1,m]|},
    hlines,
    vlines,
}

\begin{document}
    \centering
\begin{minipage}[c][16cm][c]{\linewidth}
\centering
minipage to take up plenty of vertical space

(this is meant to push the longtblr way down on the A4 page)
\end{minipage}

    \begin{longtblr}{cc} % using this to "break" at page breaks
Table                   & Header    \\
table                   & content   \\
table                   & content   \\
table                   & content   \\
\SetCell[r=2]{m} multi  & row       \\*     % <-----
                        & row \#2   \\
table                   & content   \\
table                   & content   \\
table                   & content   \\
table                   & content   \\
    \end{longtblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Note:**
Termination of table rows with `\\*` prevent break table after this rows. This is true for any type of long table (i.e. also for `longtblr` of `tabularray` package), described is in the documentation for `longtable` package documentation. It is part of LaTeX installation, also is available on [CTAN](https://ctan.org/pkg/longtable?lang=en)